# SQL Insertion without duplication

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicate-data, insertion

Is there a specific command for SQL Server in order to INSERT a lot of rows with the condition : if a row already exists in database doesn't duplicate it during insertion ?

**Edited**

In a **sqlbulkcopy**, I'd like to **avoid exception** because a row is already in the table ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `MERGE` command for this.  Example Usage.

```
CREATE TABLE #A(
 [id] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
 [C] [varchar](200) NOT NULL)


    MERGE #A AS target
    USING (SELECT 3, 'C') AS source (id, C)
    ON (target.id = source.id)
    /*Uncomment for Upsert Semantics
       WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET C = source.C */
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN    
        INSERT (id, C)
        VALUES (source.id, source.C);
```

**Edit** Though you say in your edit this is for a bulk copy? You could also investigate the "Ignore Duplicate Keys" option on your index.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it in T-SQL is [discussed here](http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx) (article is a bit old though)